# Fetching product details using eBay API

Tags: java, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I am able to get the structured data form of the category hierarchy using **getCategories()** method of **eBay's trading API**. But now i want to get the product list of some of the categories of eBay site. What would be the best way of doing this. What other API i need to use ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **findItemsByCategory** call via the **Finding API**. You pass up to 3 category IDs and eBay will search for items belonging to those categories. In addition it is possible to do the following with this call.

- Filter the results by various fields such as condition and price.
- Sort the results.
- Use pagination to split the results across several pages.

More information and examples can be found in the official eBay [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByCategory.html).